# Magento 2.2 : Syntax error or access violation: 1064 syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*'

Tags: magento2.2

When i search a keyword in search from in Magento 2 version it shows the following error. 
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have searched in DB with my searches keyword and i found it in a table name "search_synonyms". there are some other data was exist in the table. i also make some search with the text take from the table and i get same error in magetno front end again. the text was in the field "synonyms" is **hat "hats"**. the double coated text is making problem in the search in Magento front end.

i removed all of data from table "search_synonyms" and my search are working with the keyword thats makes problem age.

thanks.

you can try it. if your problem same as my this problem you may get a solution.